# TensorFlowIO: Corrupted reads of pyspark compressed spark Parquet files

Tags: tensorflow, apache-spark, parquet

I'm trying to read compressed parquet files containing `tf.Examples` (serialized to bytes) created by a Spark job.

When I read the compressed files using `tfio.IODataset.from_parquet`, there is some data corruption once the size of the records crosses a threshold. The bytes read back do not match the input bytes written to the table.

OTOH, if I write the output uncompressed, the bytes read back match the bytes written to the table exactly.

I've observed that there's a threshold at about 5073 records with a total size in the range of ~2,400,000 bytes where the compressed data read back no longer matches the input.

Any ideas what could be going on here? The threshold of 5072 seems arbitrary to me, I have a hard time believing it's a constant which factors into gzip compressed records. It's consistent with a given example schema and varying payload sizes.

If I add or remove features from the example payload, then the threshold will change.

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, IntegerType, BinaryType
import random
import string
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_io as tfio

### Step 1: Create the input data
def make_tf_example_list(num):
    out = []
    for i in range(num):
        ex = tf.train.Example()
        ex.features.feature["int_label_1"].int64_list.value.append(random.randint(0, 1))
        ex.features.feature["bytes_label_1"].bytes_list.value.append(str(random.randint(0, 2**64)).encode())
        ex.features.feature["bytes_feature_1"].bytes_list.value.append(str(random.randint(0, 2**64)).encode())
        ex.features.feature["bytes_feature_1"].bytes_list.value.append(''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_lowercase, k=random.randint(0, 100))).encode())
        for i in range(64):
            ex.features.feature["float_feature_1"].float_list.value.append(random.random())
        ex.features.feature["int_feature_2"].int64_list.value.append(random.randint(0, 2**12))
        out.append(ex.SerializeToString())
    return out

NUM_EXAMPLES = 1024*4 + 976
schema = StructType([
    StructField("id", IntegerType(), nullable=True),
    StructField("tf_example", BinaryType(), nullable=True)
])
tf_examples = list(enumerate(make_tf_example_list(NUM_EXAMPLES)))
print("Num examples:", len(tf_examples))
print("Examples bytes:", sum([len(ex) for (i, ex) in tf_examples]))

### Step 2: Write to parquet via spark dataframe
spark = SparkSession.builder.master('test-app').getOrCreate()
out_path_sp_compress = 'file:/dbfs/tmp/out.sp.gz'
df = spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.parallelize(tf_examples), schema)
df.write.parquet(out_path_sp_compress, mode="overwrite", compression='gzip')

### Step 3: Read from parquet via tfio
filenames = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(out_path_sp_compress[5:] + '/*.parquet', shuffle=False)
ds_sp_compress = filenames.interleave(
    lambda f: tfio.IODataset.from_parquet(f, columns={"id": tf.int32, "tf_example": tf.string}),
    num_parallel_calls=1
)
ex_compress = [(ex['id'], ex['tf_example']) for ex in ds_sp_compress]

### Step 4: Compare input and output data
print("id equal to input:", (tf_examples[0][0] == ex_compress[0][0]).numpy())
print("data equal to input:", (tf_examples[0][1] == ex_compress[0][1]).numpy())
```

Here are some experiments I've run and the results

| Records | Size (b) | In, Out Match |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4880 | 2310636 | Matched |
| 5064 | 2401177 | Matched |
| 5064 | 2400739 | Matched |
| 5096 | 2415187 | Not matched |
| 5096 | 2414892 | Not matched |
| 5080 | 2406966 | Not matched |
| 5072 | 2404494 | Matched |
| 5073 | 2406032 | Not Matched |
| 5072 | 2407153 | Matched |